# putting JSON data to tableview

Tags: android, tableview

### Hello I am working on a college project I needed some guidance

---

***I am trying to display the JSON data in a table view***

**JSON::** `http://54.218.73.244:7000/`

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7000/";
    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();

    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please Wait", true, false);


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONObjParser jParser = new JSONObjParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String NAME=c.getString("restaurantNAME");

                    yourData.add(new Item(NAME));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
            ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        //code specific to first list item    
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CopperChimneyDesc.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }else if(position == 1)
                    {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AroyDesc.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);                    
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

---

**CopperChimney_desc_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="BACK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

- While I have been able to achieve Populating JSON data to textview
  and listview
- How to display JSON from above URL to Table view

Comment: You can use `GridView`. There is no `TableView` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coded with IOS so that you are confused. In android we use ListView but the ios side used TableView. Just check this link for tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/